# Yellow mesh material in slab foundation cracks

Tags: foundation, slab, cracks

We recently purchased a home in central Florida, built in the late 80s, a stick-built home on a concrete slab. Today I noticed a small uplift and depression through the carpet.

Touching the carpet, there’s a faint scent of vinegar, and a moisture detector did pick up a point with moisture. Due to where it is, I’m not able to easily pull back the carpet to inspect it, but I was able to lift an edge and stuff an endoscope under it. What I found was what appears to be a crack or hole in the slab, with a yellow material with a mesh pattern in it. My understanding is that there are barriers underneath slabs, but this only appears to be a quarter of an inch under the surface. There’s also no broken material near it as far as I can tell, making me assume this isn’t a recent development.

What is this yellow material? Why does the area near it smell like vinegar? Should I be concerned?[image: Yellow material in slab]

Comment: Are you sure that's a crack with something filling it? It looks to me like a piece of an old carpet pad that had been glued down (or adhered itself over the many years a previous pad was in place) and not scraped up when the carpet was replaced.

Comment: I agree with freeman that looks like carpet pad.

Comment: That might be the case -- it's hard to see with the camera stuffed in. Though having a crack like that that's big enough to have that inside-- is that a cause for concern?